# Transparent object not appearing in render

Tags: rendering, transparency

hello im currently making a character model and the character has this transparent ruffle on her and it looks great on the viewport but every time i try to render it as a picture, the ruffles just disappears.. is there any idea on how to fix this?

its not unchecked or hidden and this happens with both eevee and cycles
I've tried raising the transparency/alpha of the object but it still doesn't appear in the rendered image

any help will be appreciated thank youu

[image]
[image]

UPDATE: i fixed it thank you! the show in render options was somehow unchecked

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, as you're saying you've checked everything relevant, it's hard to guess from those screenshots what else could be the problem. Providing the file could be helpful or at least screenshots where we can see something like settings of the object itself, the material it uses, the settings in the outliner...

Comment: In the *Object Properties* there is a *Visibility > Mask [_] Holdout* checkbox. Make sure you haven't checked this accidentally. Do you see it in the viewport when you choose *Rendered* as viewport shading mode? Do you see it when you look through the camera? Are there any keyframes?

Comment: i fixed it! thank you!! turns out i accidentally unchecked the show in renders in the visibility